# Building a query in MySql with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following loop to add several users to a database, however it only works when only one user is added into a form.

```
echo "The following names have been added to $cname<br><br>";
$query = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fname); $i++) {
  $query = $query . "INSERT INTO Students (firstName, lastName, year, class, school, email) " 
  ." VALUES ('{$fname[$i]}','{$lname[$i]}','{$year}','{$cname}','{$sch}','{$uname[$i]}'); ";
  echo $fname[$i] . " " . $lname[$i] . " " . $uname[$i];
  }

if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    error_log("Inserted {$firstname} as ID {$id}");
    return true;
} else {
    error_log("Problem inserting {$query}");
    return false;
}
```

Do I just need to add `($mysqli->query($query)` to each iteration? Or just move the 'if' clause inside the loop?  Or is there a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your echo result? and how to you pump value to this php file?

Comment: echo is blank and no data is added to DB. 'if' returns false and page redirects to form. If only one name entered in form, it works without problem.

Comment: can you show your form aas well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your query is trying to send muliple sql queries at once and it fails. You should change the way you build query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Students (firstName, lastName, year, class, school, email) VALUES ";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fname); $i++) {
  $query .= $i>0 ? ',':'';
  $query .="('{$fname[$i]}','{$lname[$i]}','{$year}','{$cname}','{$sch}','{$uname[$i]}') ";
  echo $fname[$i] . " " . $lname[$i] . " " . $uname[$i];
}
```

Comment: Better leave out the semicolon after each VALUES tuple.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as you will have to "if" it anyway - otherwise it will leave semicolon after last data set and fail.

Answer (score 0):

Better put if clause in the loop. Have you tried it?